# Are these ceiling spots in the kitchen coming from above or below?

Tags: bathroom, kitchens, ceiling, leaks

I noticed some spots on my kitchen ceiling and I’m wondering if it could be condensation from cooking — the exhaust fan isn’t actually connected to anything — or a dreaded leak from upstairs bathroom? They spots are fairly widely dispersed. Some have little dark spots right in the middle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: An above leak will usually grow expand from one spot.  Those spots seem to line up and might be joists above, acting joist shadows.

Comment: Interesting… they do seem to be in a couple patterned areas although they don’t line up super well. Any idea what that might mean? Just something superficial or should I (continue to) panic?

Comment: Joist shadows are just sections of the ceiling that collect dust/dirt more the the rest, from a touch extra moisture.  Usually lines and handy for seeing where the joists are, or letting you know the ceiling needs cleaning.  Only need to panic if scare of heights.

Answer (score 2):

These look to me like bits of greasy food that splattered onto the ceiling. The dark spot would be the food and the surrounding circle the oil that spread out a little over time. A closer inspection should allow you to confirm this. I suspect you can remove the dark spots easily but the stain surrounding them will be more tricky.

A leak wouldn't be that dispersed. And condensation (or mold from condensation) would probably cause many more spots than this.

Comment: Yeah some of them do seem like splatter just based on the pattern. Trying out my CSI skills. I’m a little more worried about the ones with the spot in the middle, which haven’t come off (though they may have been there awhile). Any recommendations for monitoring?